# Server push solution on Rails

Tags: iphone, android, ruby-on-rails

I'm working on a multi-platform (iPhone, Android, WM7, web), multiplayer game with Rails backend (2.3.10) and needs server push functionality. What is the best Rails solution for handling server push that works with multiple client side platforms? Is it Juggernaut, Comet, Cramp, pusherapp, or ?

Answer (score 2):

One option would be to use [Faye](https://github.com/faye/faye) (Ryan B. did a [screencast on Faye](http://railscasts.com/episodes/260-messaging-with-faye)).

My experience is that Eventmachine constitutes a great foundation for doing event-based stuff - Pusherapp is build on top of this. So if you want to take on the more difficult solution, you should consider writing your own pub/sub server - perhaps using [em-websocket](https://github.com/igrigorik/em-websocket).

Lastly, while some consider Pusherapp expensive, it really is both simple and rock solid.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to deal with a multitude of weird mobile browsers. If they support HTML5 websockets, use it! Pusherapp seems to be great for that.

I think Pusherapp also has Flash fallback for clients that don't support websockets yet.

I guess that with websockets + Flash fall-back you'll have 98% of the modern smartphones covered. Give it a try.

Comment: Actually I'm developing native mobile apps, not using mobile browsers. Couple of concerns with pusherapp, one is their expensive pricing plan when it goes into effect, $199/month for 5000 max connections which I don't think is enough for games with millions of players, second is they don't have library for WM7.

Answer (score 0):

I created a gem in order to create a central push notifications, it supports iOS and Android at the moment, but i will add more platforms.

here is the link: https://github.com/NicosKaralis/pushmeup